# Perl: Difference between two array index values

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays input:

```
@a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
@b = (2, 2, 3, 6, 8);
```

Output:

print 1,4,5 difference in first array.
print 2,6,8 difference in second array.

I tried this, but I don't no which module to use.

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

@a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
@a = (2, 2, 3, 6, 8);

# get items from array @a that are not in array @b
my @minus = array_minus( @a, @b );
print @minus;exit;
```

I want to print the difference between index values.

Comment: Is this homework? Please [edit] your post to include some code you have written to solve this problem. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my @diff_indexes = grep { $a[$_] != $b[$_] } 0..$#a;

my @a_diff_values = @a[ @diff_indexes ];
my @b_diff_values = @b[ @diff_indexes ];
```

Reference: [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)